# how to delete row instantly which contain string(tr_obj ) using js

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function DeleteUser(tr_obj,ul_userid)
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to delete user "+ul_userid+"?"))
    {
             $.ajax({
                 url:"/core/ajax_delete.php",
                 data: { login_id:ul_userid,action:'USER'},
                 async: false,

                 success: function(data) 
                 {
                    if(data==1)
                    {  
                        DeleteTemplateRow(tr_obj);
                    }

                  }
          });   

    }
}
```

I tried with many option but its not getting delete instantly

```
 function DeleteSelectedRow(tr_obj)  // tr_obj returns tr_1,tr_0..
 {     
          $(tr_obj).remove();
        //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
        //$("#user_listing_table").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr_obj)
  }
```

Row getting delete but not instantly,i need to refresh each time of deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the reference class or id for that table just do this

eg: if that table has the id myTable

if you want to remove all children of that dom including header

```
$("#myTable").empty()
```

if you want to remove except header

```
$("#myTable").slice(1).remove()
```

Comment: no its no working as same i need to refresh the page... if i alert that tr_obj" alert(tr_obj); " it is returning 'tr_o' for first table value. so how can i delete instantly

Comment: you are calling "DeleteTemplateRow" that function is missing in your post

Comment: no see the next code segment i have displayed below

Comment: but in below code the function name is "DeleteSelectedRow"

Comment: where you called DeleteUser and what parameter you mapped with tr_obj, is it table dom object or id of any table

Comment: problem solved.  actually tr_obj is getting with ''  as ('tr_obj' ) after getting removed its working fine above code is correct. "DeleteSelectedRow(tr_obj)" is a function which calls a above function